# Angularjs, How to avoid race condition in controller events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a paging module in my project which contains a directive that generates new controllers each time I move to another page.

Everything worked fine until I had to add a shortcut that moves to another page.

The problem is that the shortcut event is fired in each paging controller in the project, which causing races.

I tried to check in the shortcut function if the current controller is the right one (the one that is active, the controller that represents the current page that the user is on) and only if that is true - to proceed with the movePage function.

Unfortunately, I'm still getting races. When I try the shortcut it moves 2-3-4 pages ahead while the expected behavior is moving to only one page above the current.

Is there any way in Angular 1 to erase old controller instances?
Or maybe check if the current controller corresponds to active view?

Comment: please show some code

Comment: Can listen to router events which provide details about current and previous route/state. Nobody can help without seeing some code